# Problems passing numpy array to c++ via ctypes

Tags: python, c++, c, numpy, ctypes

From Python, I want to leverage a fast and complicated algorithm, which takes an array as argument. The  code is someone else's c++ code, which in turn utilises backend c code.

The interface looks something like this (myfunc.cpp):

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <vector>

#define NO_IMPORT_ARRAY
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

extern "C" {
#include <my/myfunc.h>
}

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <iostream>

PyObject * myfunc(PyArrayObject & pyArray)
{
    std::cout << pyArray.descr << std::endl;
    std::cout << pyArray.descr->type_num << std::endl; //This fails to print, python crashes on my mac
    // check data type
    assert(pyArray.descr->type_num == PyArray_UBYTE);
    std::cout << pyArray.flags << std::endl;
    assert(pyArray.flags & NPY_FORTRAN);
    // ...
}
```

to which I have added:

```
extern "C" {
    PyObject * run_myfunc(PyArrayObject & pyArray)
    {
        return myfunc(pyArray);
    };
}
```

I have next to no knowledge of C or C++, and I also lack a debugger set up. I have successfully compiled myfunc.cpp, and the myfunc.c file, and created a shared library. 
Next, I try to use this shared library with types in python (ctypes to avoid any other large dependencies e.g. boost).

I have tried many different approaches in Python, the gists of each are:

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('lib_myfunc.so')

# Approach 1
def myfunc():
    lib.run_myfunc.argtypes = [np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.uint8, flags="F_CONTIGUOUS", ndim=2)]
    data = np.ones((20, 20), order='F', dtype=np.uint8)
    return lib.run_myfunc(data)  # Python crashes here

# Approach 2:
def myfunc():
    data = np.ones((20, 20), order='F', dtype=np.uint8)
    c_uint8_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8)
    data_p = data.ctypes.data_as(c_uint8_p)
    return lib.run_myfunc(data_p)  # Python crashes here
```

The python thread crashes, saying:

```
Exception Type:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
```

This seems to occur when the C++ code tries to access `pyArray.descr->type_num`, which suggests that the data type of the array isn't being passed into the function properly.
Any help very welcome, this has been causing me trouble for days!

Comment: The function takes a `PyArrayObject` argument and returns a `PyObject *`, so it may be part of a CPython extension module that also happens to have a C API defined in `my/myfunc.h`. Building and using the extension module in this case would be a simpler option.

Comment: Calling this using ctypes requires holding the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), so you would use `lib = ctypes.PyDLL('lib_myfunc.so')`, and set `lib.run_myfunc.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object];` `lib.run_myfunc.restype = ctypes.py_object`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks @eryksun, `lib.run_myfunc.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object];` was all I needed. Please post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: No, that's not all you need. You need to use `PyDLL` or `PYFUNCTYPE` to get a function pointer that doesn't release the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock). Never operate on Python objects without holding the GIL.